# Determine whether the series converge

Tags: sequences-and-series

$\sum\limits_{i=3}^\infty \frac{1}{n(log(n)(log(log(n))}$

and

$\sum\limits_{i=3}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{(2n^2-3n+1)(ln((n)+ln(n)^2}$

I suppose the first one would diverge via the comparison test, but I'm not sure which series to compare it to.

As for the second, I don't know how to approach them.

Comment: There's a formatting error with your second integral.  Please fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Any form the second term (in the denominator of the second series) be; assuming the following limit: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{3/2}u_n=0<\infty$$ the comparison test tells us it converges.

Comment: $+1\quad \ddot\smile^{+1}\quad$

Comment: I second amWhy's comment!

Answer (score 1):

The first sum diverges by the integral test.  That is, look at the integral

$$\int_3^N \frac{dx}{x \, \log{x} \, \log{\log{x}}}$$

as $N \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: how would you show this diverges? i would be very interested to see a proof of this.

Comment: See here.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence  
I prefer the OP to do the integral out himself, which is doable through, e.g., substitution.  That said, the result is that the integral evaluates to $\log{\log{\log{N}}}$, which of course diverges, albeit tortuously slow.

Comment: Nicely done, Ron. Killed the poor logarithmic fraction. +1 :D

Answer (score 1):

For the first, there is a nice general test in Knopp's book on series, about:

$$\sum_n \frac{1}{e^{(a-1)n} n^{a_0} \log^{a_1}(n) \log_2^{a_2}(n) ... \log_p^{a_p}(n)}$$

Where $\log_p(n) = \log \log ... \log(n)$ ($p$ times).

And it says the series is convergent iff the first $a$ from the left that is not equal to $1$, is greater than $1$.

*Sketch of proof: the main point lies in the proof that $\sum_n\dfrac{1}{n\log n \dots\log_{p-1}n\log_p^a n}$ (that is, with exponent $1$ except on the last) is convergent iff $a>1$. For this compare the series with the integral $\int \dfrac{\mathrm dx}{x\log x \dots\log_{p-1}x\log_p^a x}$, and notice a primitive is $\frac{(\log_p x)^{1-a}}{1-a}$. If $a>1$ and there are other factors beyond $(\log_p n)^a$, just split $(\log_p n)^a=(\log_p n)^{a-\epsilon}(\log_p n)^\epsilon$ and $(\log_p n)^\epsilon$ grows faster than the remaining factors.*

For the second, the general term is $o\left(1\over{n^{3/2}}\right)$, hence the series is convergent.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can repeatedly apply Cauchy Condensation Test for the first result. For the second one, you can get an upper bound by ignoring the $\ln$ part. Then compare it against a series like $C/n^{3/2}$ for some constant, then this must converge.