# What's the Point That Rudin is Trying to Make After Theorem 3.29?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

After proving Theorem 3.29 in page 63 of Rudin's *"Principles of Mathematical Analysis"*, Rudin says that "this procedure may evidently be continued", what procedure is he talking about exactly? Moreover, I don't really understand the point he is trying to make after that before going to define the number $e$. It would really be helpful for me if someone could explain more in detail and intuitively what he is trying to say.

[image]
[image]

Comment: For the benefit of those who don't have the book in front of them, can you give the name of the theorem, or its statement, or its general topic, please?

Comment: The text is online...[here](https://notendur.hi.is/~vae11/%C3%9Eekking/principles_of_mathematical_analysis_walter_rudin.pdf)

Comment: @kimchilover would it be o.k if I add a few pictures from the book? It would be really long to write everything that could be relevant.

Comment: I've taken the liberty to add the relevant snippet of the book in. If you think this is inappropriate, feel free to roll back.

Comment: @YiFan Oh that's great it's exactly what I was about to do, thank you.

Comment: Here the procedure means, the author is telling about applying condensation test and as roughly some seies $\sum f(n,p)$ is convergent for some $p>1$ and divergent for $p<1$ ,so from this observation one may think of about some boundary of convergence.

Comment: @who Applying condensation test to what? Every possible series of reals involving some fixed p (that satisfies the conditions of Cauchy condensation test theorem)? And what exactly a boundary of convergence means?

Answer (score 3):

The procedure in question is that used in the proof to deduce the convergence of the series $\sum \frac{1}{n(\log n)^p},$ and from the next sentence he means the case when you apply this procedure to monotonically decreasing series with smaller terms, specifically those of the form $$\sum \frac{1}{n(\log n)^p(\log \log n)^p(\log\log\log n)^p\cdots(\log\log\log\log\cdots\log n)^p}.$$

What he's saying in the next paragraph is that if you consider series of this form, for increasingly many iterations of the logarithm function, then you would always discover that we always have the series divergent for $p\le 1$ and convergent otherwise. However, when you take two values of $p$ that are as close to each other as you wish, but so that one is $\le 1$ and the other is $>1,$ then the corresponding series differ very little from each other, yet one always diverges and the other always converges. His claim is now that one might intuitively expect that there would be some sort of separation, a cut as it were, in the values of $p,$ so that all convergent series of this type are in one part and all divergent ones are in the other part. Now the stupendous line: Rudin claims that *no matter how we make this concept of cut precise, no such separation can exist.*

Of course all these claims are unsubstantiated, but he refers his reader to Knopp.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much, it's much clearer now! Tough, there's still one thing I don't entirely understand. By a separation, or a cut, you mean that there is some property - some proposition that holds for  the convergent series, but doesn't hold for  the divergent ones? If so, then what does it mean how precise this property is ? How you formally state that it doesn't matter how precise a proposition is?

Comment: The point is to have, in your sum, different values for all these $p$, and specifically that all are equal to $1$ except the last (otherwise you can trivially find out convergence or divergence according to the first factor, starting from the left, for which $p\ne1$. It makes no sense to have the same $p$ for all factors. There is a section in Knopp precisely about this. You have thus an infinite scale of comparison for convergence/divergence, but as Rudin states, it won't be enough to get a "boundary".

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut  why is it trivial to find out convergence or divergence according to the first factor that isn't 1, if it isn't the case that all values of $p$ are 1 except for the last? What do you mean by an infinite scale of comparison for convergence/divergence?

Comment: @MichaelNovak (1) Consider [this](https://tinyurl.com/yyo5h53e) and generalize to any number of factors. Then use the [integral test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence). That's for the interesting case. Now assume different values of $p_i$, above. Consider the first, from the left, that is $\ne0$. Then if it's $>1$, the terms are less than the same series with only factors up to $p_i$, so it converges.

Comment: (2) If it's $<1$, then replace $p_i$ with $p'_i$ such that $p_i<p'_i<1$, compensate with a factor $u_n=(\log\log\dots\log n)^{p'_i-p_i}$ in numerator, and show that $u_n$ grows faster than the remaining factors after $p_i$ in denominator, so that the series is divergent. Thus, the value of $p_i$ (the first that is $\ne1$) is enough to conclude. If it's not clear, I'll write a separate answer.

Comment: @MichaelNovak Regarding the infinite scale of comparison, just notice that $f_p(n)=n(\log n)(\log\log n)\dots(\log\log\dots\log n)$ (with $p$ logs in the last factor) grows faster that $f_{p-1}$ for all $p$. It's useful to prove convergence of a series by a comparison test ([this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test) or [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test)). In France, the case with one log is called the [Bertrand series](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A9rie_de_Bertrand), the general case allows for finer comparisons.

Comment: @MichaelNovak It's similar to using the family $x^n$ to compare growth of functions, for instance. Of course, the $f_p(n)$ defined above all grow slower than $n^2$.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357145/determine-whether-the-series-converge/357169#357169

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Sorry, I didn't yet learned about integrals and the integral test, as I'm on the third chapter of baby Rudin, and integrals are introduced only in the sixth chapter. Is there a different way of understanding it?

Comment: @MichaelNovak The idea of *cut* or *separation* here is still quite intuitive, as hinted at in his punchline. Think geometrically. Then the claim is that one might suppose there's a fence separating all convergent series of this kind from those that diverge. Rudin claims that no such separation exists -- or, in other words, that the convergent series blend smoothly into the divergent ones, with no demarcation between them. It's really a big, non-intuitive claim!

Comment: @Allawonder Oh now it makes sense, I didn't understand that he is talking about the graphs. Btw, is there some picture online of this smooth transition between the convergent and the divergent series? And how do you respond to to what Jean-Claude Arbaut is saying and to the answer Christian Blatter gave?

Answer (score 2):

The idea is this: We are discussing series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k$ with  terms $a_k>0$. Some of these series converge, some diverge. Where is the boundary?
Hereabout one can prove the following facts (and some of this is contained in Rudin's *Principles*):

If the series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k$ with $a_k>0$ is convergent you can construct a series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k$ with $$\lim_{k\to\infty}{b_k\over a_k}=\infty\ ,$$
which is still convergent. Conversely: If $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k$ is divergent you can construct a series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k$ with $$\lim_{k\to\infty}{b_k\over a_k}=0\ ,$$
which is still divergent.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get it. Could you explain how is that related to what Rudin is saying? Like what is $\{a_k\}$ and what is $\{b_k\}$, in Rudin's explanation? What you are saying is that the procedure that Rudin is talking about is the construction of $\{b_k\}$ for each $\{a_k\}$? And I still don't understand what does a boundary mean.